# Vue "item is not defined" in a "v-for"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to use `v-for` to render for each item, but I got this:

```
    vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: item is not defined"

    found in

    ---> <Welcome>
           <Main>
             <Root>
```

I tried to comment some codes like this:

```html
    <div style="padding-top: 20px"  v-for="(item,index) in weekRank" v-bind:key="index">
      <b>{{item.username}} </b> {{item.point}}  / 10
      <div v-if="item.point>10" class="progress deep-purple lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
        <!--<div class="determinate  deep-purple darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>-->
      </div>
      <div v-else class="progress blue lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
        <!--<div class="determinate  blue darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the errors are still there. It seems the problem is not caused by `getProgressBarStyle` but by `<div v-if="item.point>10"` or codes above it, because they point where `item` was referred.

So I commented these:

```html
    <!--<<div v-else class="progress blue lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
      <div class="determinate  blue darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>
    </div>-->
```

And now the errors disappear, but why? I commented these `html` codes which are supposed to be not related.

I've reproducted this problem with all required code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pluvet/40g57smw/4/) (Press F12 to see the errors, please)

Preview:

```html
    <div style="padding-top: 20px"  v-for="(item,index) in weekRank" v-bind:key="index">

      <b>{{item.username}} </b> {{item.point}}  / 10
      <div v-if="item.point>10" class="progress deep-purple lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
        <div class="determinate  deep-purple darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>
      </div>
      <div v-else class="progress blue lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
        <div class="determinate  blue darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to reference `item` inside method `getProgressBarStyle()`, but you name the parameter to this method as `todo`. You just need to update `todo` to `item`. Also I'd consider returning an object for the `:style` assignment instead of a string. Also you need to probably pass `item` instead of `index` to this method in the template as you are attempting to use properties on `item` such as `point`:

HTML:

```
<div class="determinate  blue darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item)"></div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    weekRank: [
      { index: 0, username: "Learn JavaScript", point: 9 },
      { index: 1, username: "Learn Vue", point: 7 },
      { index: 2, username: "Play around in JSFiddle", point: 5 },
      { index: 3, username: "Build something awesome", point: 1 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getProgressBarStyle: function(item) { // change this to 'item'
        if (item.point >= 10) return { 'width': 100%' };
        return { 'width': item.point * 10 + '%' };
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4zvrj7cm/).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry to make some errors when moving my code to jsfiddle. Now I modified it to make it consistent with my project code. (index=>item.point, todo=>point). And the error remains. I guess it's beacause I passed `item.point` to `getProgressBarStyle` instead of `item`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Yeah, you'll need to no matter what pass something other than `index` to this method, but it would be up to you how you want to handle getting `point` to the method to calculate styles. Please mark the answer if it help resolve your issue. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Vue component code, you seem to have some errors on your `getProgressBarStyle` method where you're giving a `todo` parameter but are referencing `item` which throws that error. I've used the template code you've provided in the snippet below as well

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    weekRank: [
      { index: 0, username: "Learn JavaScript", point: 9 },
      { index: 1, username: "Learn Vue", point: 7 },
      { index: 2, username: "Play around in JSFiddle", point: 5 },
      { index: 3, username: "Build something awesome", point: 1 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   getProgressBarStyle: function(point){
     if (point >= 10) return 'width: 100%';
        return 'width: ' + point * 10 + '%'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
    <h3>Rank</h3>
    <body>
    <div class="" style="display: flex;">      
      <div style="min-width: 300px;flex-grow: 1;">
        <h6><b>details: </b></h6>
        <div style="padding-top: 20px"  v-for="(item,index) in weekRank" v-bind:key="index">
      <b>{{item.username}} </b> {{item.point}}  / 10
      <div v-if="item.point>10" class="progress deep-purple lighten-3" style="flex-grow: 1;height: 16px;">
        <div class="determinate  deep-purple darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="determinate  blue darken-1" :style="getProgressBarStyle(item.point)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better way. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, no problem! You can upvote it or tag it as the answer if you found it helpful :)